# "Configuration parameter is required for the "sources" component." error after upgrade to 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2, product

After I upgraded from 2.2.3 to 2.3.2 I am getting this error when I try to open a product in the admin:

**array(4) { [0]=> string(84) "The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "sources" component." [1]=> string(275147) "**

The full stack trace can be found on https://pastebin.com/BCCKQDCV.

Any idea where to look?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: In my case, I have disabled MSI and now Magento is not allowing me to edit the product. Throws this error.